# Bypass excel csv formula conversion on fields starting with + or -

Tags: excel, csv

I have a csv file with contents:

```
"x","y","-z"
```

When I import it I get:

[image]

How can I bypass this conversion?

**Update**

If you try:

```
   "x","y",="-z,a"
```

The ",a" is not imported.

If you put a space in front:

```
   "x","y",=" -z"
```

or

```
   "x","y"," -z"
```

it will work fine

Comment: Best answer is by MikeD

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is that by using the CSV extension, you are forcing excel to interpret the file using its very strict CSV conventions, and this will often go against whatever it is you're trying to do unless the CSV file was originally created by Excel. Your easiest, and most reliable method of importing this CSV file, is to rename it to a TXT file, and then use the import function in excel to coerce columns in exactly the way you want.

Comment: Therefore, it is a manual job and is impossible to auto import these csv files?

Comment: Not at all, any scripting language you're using certainly has a way to manipulate the file system. Your question wasn't tagged with any programming language, so I assumed you were doing it manually anyways. If you're using VBA in excel, there's an easy command (`FileCopy srcFile, srcFile & ".txt"`) that will make a temporary copy of the file with the new extension. After you open it, you can then get rid of it with `Kill srcFile & ".txt"`

Answer (score 16):

Prefix the values with equals signs

```
="x",="y",="-z"
```

Comment: Is there a way to import it as text without putting the "'" in front?

Comment: Without using a format other than CSV, I do not believe so. Depending on the text in each column in a CSV, Excel will act differently. It seems that if you provide a character (such as x) it will display as a character, however if you prefix a character with a mathematical operator (i.e. -) Excel tries to reference a cell as a number with the designation provided (in this case z).

Comment: Interestingly if you have "x","y",="-z,a" then the ",a" is not even imported!

Comment: actually I think Excel is keying off of the - to make a formula, it's a problem with string constants in Excel

Answer (score 11):

There is a complete difference in using Excel > Import and double-click a .CSV file. Different parsers are used.

Based on the comments above, I figured out that **prepending a space** before a '+' or '-' sign works for the double-click .CSV file case. So my file now contains e.g.

```
" +14";" -Foo"
```

Comment: THIS should be the accepted answer. After hours searching through quotes, aphostrophes, etc, A SPACE is what i needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

I tried your first example in Excel 2003 and could reproduce your #NAME eror.

My solution was to open the text file and to specify the 3rd column as "Text" in the import wizard (3rd page) - along with choosing the correct delimiter and text qualifier (2nd page).

No changes needed to the text file.

Comment: A much better answer than any of the above

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to solve such problem directly during the conversion, by giving the right column format, example: use *Text* format for the column that should contain operation sign:

[image: Text format on the column]

Check this detail post: http://ask.osify.com/qa/854

Answer (score 0):

Find and replace every instance of
`+`
with
`' +`

A single quote and space at the beginning should cancel out any `+`, `-`, or `=`.

Comment: It did not work for me: the `'` is kept in the string column.

Answer (score 0):

You also will need to transform 1.5 numbers to 1,5 strings, so they don't changed to date type values.

For + - = I use space method " +...." - not great, but for my task was enough.